# Word, Phrase or Idiom for "seemingly OK, but internally bad"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There are things that are seemingly OK but have problems within. For instance a food might seem OK but be poisonous. Or **a translation might seem OK but in fact be awful since it has omitted or changed the main message**. How can we describe such things? Even people might be seemingly nice but internally wicked!

I am particularly interested for words/phrases/idioms that describe the above-mentioned like translations.

For example:

> This translations is *the word I am looking for*, it seems OK but
>   actually says something completely different to what the original
>   sentence says!

I am interested especially in a word with a formal register, which is suitable to be written in an academic text. Is *outwardly good/flawless* a good fit?

Comment: A 'sugar-coated pill' is something that is good but tastes bad and is therefore made palatable. I think you are looking for something like 'sugar-coated poison' - it is made palatable but in fact it is detrimental.

Comment: @NigelJ Very interesting! But this word implies that someone has done that deliberately and *poison* is a very strong word. Can you provide more equivalents?

Comment: _Deceptive mistranslation_ is how I would word it, myself.

Answer (score 1):

How about **misleading**?

: to lead in a wrong direction or into a mistaken action or belief often by deliberate deceit  [Merriam-Webster's].

*Donald Trump gave the American press misleading information in order to support his twisted agenda.*

Answer (score 1):

"Superficially good" fits the translation example, but not the poison so much. Other options are "apparently", "seemingly", "to first appearances".

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used phrase for this situation is: ***appearances can be deceiving***

TFD(idioms):

> **[appearances can be deceiving](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/appearances+can+be+deceiving)**
>   Appearances do not always convey accurate information.
>   That house sure looks beautiful on the
>   outside, but appearances can be deceiving. What did the inspector say
>   about the foundation?
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

It is formal enough to be used in academic texts as can be seen by the examples at:
[Google search for "appearances can be deceiving" in scholarly articles](https://www.google.com/search?q="appearances+can+be+deceiving"+in+scholarly+articles)